# Wrap superagent in a higher order function to have global error logging?

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling, webpack, superagent

So I want to use `winston` to log all the requests my application makes. I make all API requests via `superagent`, and I basically want to set up some kind of middleware like:

```
// Global error middleware
superagent.on('request', req => winston.log(req))
```

And then in *another file*, import `superagent` *as normal* and have it work:

```
import superagent from 'superagent'
const request = superagent.get('url' ..etc)
```

I don't want to have to be importing my own wrapped function, because I am afraid other developers on the team will forget this practice, import directly from superagent, and thus avoid the error logging. I obviously also don't want to have to write logging into dozens of instances of `superagent` boilerplate.

I've googled around and found, surprisingly, basically no solutions. Is there a way? Alternatively I guess I could set an alias in my webpack config?

Answer (score -1):

You could create a sub-package in your project and link to that. You'd need to implement a few files:

First create a folder for that sub-package, in my case: `lib/superagent+logger` *(relative to the main project folder)*

The names can be changed as you wish, except of the `name` in the following file.

`lib/superagent+logger/package.json`

```
{
    "name": "superagent",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "superagent wrapper that adds a global logger",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "superagent": "latest"
    }
}
```

**the name is important to mock superagent and can't be changed**

`lib/superagent+logger/index.js`

```
var superagent = require("superagent");

function logRequest(req){
    //that's the part you'd want to implement
    console.log('tracing signal to ', JSON.stringify(req.url));
}

function Smith(){ return superagent.apply(null, arguments).on('request', logRequest); }
Object.setPrototypeOf(Smith, superagent);
module.exports = Object.assign( 
    Smith, 
    {
        Request(method, url){
            return superagent.Request(method, url).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        agent(options){
            return superagent.agent(options).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        Response(req){
            return superagent.Response(req).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        acl(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.acl(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        bind(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.bind(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        checkout(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.checkout(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        connect(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.connect(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        copy(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.copy(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        delete(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.delete(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        get(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.get(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        head(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.head(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        link(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.link(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        lock(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.lock(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        "m-search": function(url, data, fn){
            return superagent["m-search"](url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        merge(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.merge(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        mkactivity(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.mkactivity(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        mkcalendar(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.mkcalendar(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        mkcol(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.mkcol(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        move(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.move(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        notify(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.notify(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        options(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.options(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        patch(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.patch(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        post(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.post(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        propfind(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.propfind(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        proppatch(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.proppatch(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        purge(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.purge(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        put(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.put(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        rebind(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.rebind(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        report(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.report(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        search(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.search(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        subscribe(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.subscribe(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        trace(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.trace(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        unbind(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.unbind(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        unlink(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.unlink(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        unlock(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.unlock(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        unsubscribe(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.unsubscribe(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        },
        del(url, data, fn){
            return superagent.del(url, data, fn).on('request', logRequest)
        }
    }
);

//wrapper built and ready to use
console.log("Hello Mr Anderson\n");
```

and in your actual project:

`/package.json`

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "superagent": "file:lib/superagent+logger"
    }
}
```

And a simple test:

```
var request = require("superagent");
void request.get("http://google.de").end();
```

**Edit:**

I wrote out the part in `lib/superagent+logger/index.js` that previously was built dynamically and confused you.

**+** no dynamically built methods
**-** no dynamically built methods

No surprizes with the module, but it doesn't adapt to changes in the inner `superagent` implementation/version either; you'll have to do this manually.

And as I'm reading this there might be a few methods you'd want to remove. My main goal was how to inject/load this wrapper into the actual project, not on superagent itself.

Comment: Your `index.js` is extremely hard to read, full of weird syntax choices and regex. Care to explain what it's actually doing? Replacing `superagent` methods?

Comment: @John Doe. No, it doesn't modify superagent at all. It wraps it. First it creates a wrapper for the superagent method, named "Smith", and it creates a wrapper for each method on superagent that forwards the call to the respective superagent method and appends a `.on('request', logRequest)`. The "weird" part creates a dynamic function body as a string to name the wrapper methods, and give them the same arguments, ... basically just sugar for the error reports *(I guess 3AM payed its toll)*. You can log `methods` to check out the built function body. I add a simpler version in a moment.

Comment: Couldn't get this working at all. Why are you using a local file and then installing it via npm anyways? Why not just alias it?

Comment: @JohnDoe, because I don't know enough about aliasing to meet your requirements. "something" that behaves to the main app (and resolves by `require('superagent')`) like the actual superagent package, but runs some additional code. To me this sounded like a module, and what I'm trying to resolve here is the conflict of two modules, both by the same name (superagent) in the same app.

Comment: I am using ES6 anyways, so module resolution is different. Thanks for your effort though, if no one else replies I'll accept it as a solution.